# Covert from literal HEX value to INT MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, string, hex

I have a situation where i need to get the integer value from a literal hex.
Example: "ff" equals 255 in decimal, but if i use the HEX("ff") function it returns 6666.
Is it possible to get it to return 255? Like a=10, b=11... and so on

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to convert hexadecimal representation to decimal one then you must use [CONV() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv).

> ```
> SELECT CONV('ff', 16, 10);
> ```
>
> ```
> | CONV('ff', 16, 10) |
> | :----------------- |
> | 255                |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=afcdc1ad5b7862a21c6dfbea0234f7a0)*

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what i was looking for